# Eagle CAD: PDF scaling problem? (tone transfer method)

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, eaglecad

First of all, how do you export your layout to PDF in order to create the PCB using **tone transfer method**?

In the past I created one small PCB by doing the following: print > PDF format (scale=1). No problems.
However today I installed Eagle (5.11), tried to do the same but, after the PCB is created I found that I got a scaling problem in my hands. Headers don't fit in holes! I tried to export PDF with different (virtual) "printers" and, with SmartPDF I got the best result. However still doesn't fit perfectly with headers.

Thus, I tried "Cam Processor" with "layout2.cam", exported layout to an EPS file format and printed that. Now the holes fit perfectly.

How do you export layout to PDF when using tone transfer method?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried contacting Eagle support?

Comment: what pdf reader are you using to print it? Adobe has notorious problems with messing up scaling.

Comment: Why bother converting to pdf? Just print from eagle to  your transfer paper. I do it like this and it has worked every time. I would avoid conversion processes wherever possible since there are usually problems associated with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I type in the command line of eagle.

DISPLAY NONE

DISPLAY BOTTOM PADS VIAS

EXPORT IMAGE C:\PathForImage\ImageName.PNG MONOCHROME 600

Then I do an invert in GIMP and print it.  It will be 600 DPI and the PNG seem to print correctly onto my label backing wax paper that I iron onto the board.

Comment: I didn't notice that opening that image with any image viewer program it prints to scale. I thougth images were used just to publish on web or other docs. Just for reference Im using FastStone Viewer to invert colors and print it.Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your image software.  High-resolution PNG actually works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the scaling is happening during printing the PDF? Check that you don't choose something like 'shrink to printable area' or such - this will also scale down small PDFs.

Comment: I don't think so. I used different virtual (pdf) printers: the default one and SmartPDF. Scaling=none=actual size=whatever. Different results, better results with SmartPDF. I also tried different PDF readers (foxit, pdf xchange). I have been googling it and someone at diyAudio forum recommend to use CAM processor to avoid scaling problems. I already printed the EPS image generated by CAM processor and its actually printed correctly, no scaling errors!

Comment: The issue wouldn't be printing from Eagle to PDF, it is when you print the PDF to the printer.  The default for most PDF viewers is scale to fit page while printing.  I've always used images, rather than PDF, in case I want to adjust something else.

Answer (score 0):

i use a virtual printer software called 'BullzipPDFPrinter' it can make the print as PNG,BMP,PDF and other various kinds of formats then i print it using Adobe Acrobat reader but watch out for the scaling , you have to make the scale at 'none' and it will work for you ;).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered something weird: Have had the same problem.

In the print dialog there is an option called "Area:", if this is set to "Full" Eagle is going to scale the print down, probably to fit everything to the printable area. If it is set to "Window" I get a 1:1 print. It's not exactly obvious :) But it seems to work!